# How to make a parallax fullscreen background without losing proportion

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-animations, parallax

So I want to make a background what moves with the mouse. The background needs to be about 15% bigger than the screen for the effect to be good. I'm not using a tilable image.

I've tried to use `background-size:115%` but the issue is the image is horizontal and if the browser size is not wide enough, we can see the edges of the image.

Using `background-size:cover` don't work because I can't animate it since there's no outter image.

Using an image with `width:115%; height:115%` will make the image disproportionate.

I read somewhere that using position absolute and animating the top and left on a div that mesure 115% with the background on cover would be bad for performance because the body size recalculate every frame?

Comment: Can you please share some sample code using codepen or jsfiddle for us to look at what you have?

Comment: What's propostion?

Comment: I meant proportion -> aspect ratio of the original image

Comment: I guess [this JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k7zyqy23/2/) works! but it uses position absolute and may slow the computer down... but it's responsive!

Answer (score 1):

One posibility is to use just a transform in Z, and some perspective.

Then play with pespective origin on mouse move

```js
var mouseMove = function(e) {
  var elem = document.getElementById('container');
  elem.style.perspectiveOrigin = e.pageX +'px ' + e.pageY + 'px';
}

window.onload = function() {
  this.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
}
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 400px;
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/51021/pexels-photo-51021.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  transform: translateZ(100px);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
</div>
```